# combine 2 SearchResultCollection

Tags: c#, search, active-directory

We are in the process of moving employees to a new Active Directory OU. I have an applicatin where users can search for an employee by the DisplayName (or as much of it as they know) in AD and it returns to them a list of all employees found. The filter looks like this: `(&(displayName={0}*))`, where the {0} is replaced with the search criteria that a user enters. The application searches active directory and returns a SearchResultCollection with the results. It now needs to be able to search the old path in AD as well as the new one and then combine the results into one SearchResultCollection that is sorted by LastName, FirstName that I can iterate over.

Problem is, it doesn't look like there are any methods to Join 2 SearchResultCollections. Am I missing something?

Comment: Get first as a List<> then use AddRange() method to add 2nd to first results.

Comment: That's all fine and good. I actually tried that, but the calling method is expecting a SearchResultCollection back and I was unable to cast the list back to a SearchResultCollection.